# Magento 2.3.7 Compilation Error

Tags: magento2.3.7

Having a slight issue with compilation after upgrading from Magento 2.3.5-p2 to Magento 2.3.7

The following error received on step 6 of compilation

```
Magento\Framework\Setup\Option\AbstractConfigOption 
Incompatible argument type: Required type: int. Actual type: string;
File:vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Option/AbstractConfigOption.php
```

System.log shows

```
main.ERROR: Error during compilation
#0 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/Decorator/Interceptions.php(85): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Compiler\Log\Log->report()
#1 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/InterceptionCache.php(59): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\Decorator\Interceptions->getList('/home/sites/...')
#2 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\InterceptionCache->doOperation()
#3 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(206): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process(Object(Closure), Object(Closure))
#4 /vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
```

Tried disabling all custom modules, still facing this issue - thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up downloading a vanilla Magento 2.3.7 and comparing composer.json

The composer.json file had not updated, so needed to manually add them in for sections "require dev" and adding in "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.1" in section "require"

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"version": "2.3.7",
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.7",
    "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/",
            "generated/code/"
        ]
    },
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    }
},
"require-dev": {
    "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
    "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
    "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^2.7",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
    "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
    "phpstan/phpstan": ">=0.12.3 <=0.12.23",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4"
},
"conflict": {
    "gene/bluefoot": "*"
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

}